# nvidia-346 driver works, but UI shows "nouveau"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-settings

I am running 14.04 on a lenovo y510P with a  GT 750M graphics card and I installed the NVIDIA-346 driver from xorg to run CUDA 7. CUDA 7 requires the 346 driver. I didn't install the driver which came with the CUDA toolkit. I installed the open source driver from xorg.

After I install the driver, CUDA toolkit and CUDA samples, CUDA seems to work fine. I ran the executable deviceQuery which is part of the CUDA samples and it runs showing me the specs for my GPU (GT 750M) and its CUDA capabilities.

But when I check if the driver is used by going to **System Settings -> Software and Updates -> Additional Drivers**, the driver being used is the nouveau driver from Xorg. There isn't even an option to switch to the 346 driver (there is to 331, 331-updates and 340)

When I check if the driver is part of the kernel through `lsmod | grep nvidia` I can see a module with the name nvidia.

When I run `nvidia-detector` it returns `none`

When I run 'nvidia-smi` the output is [image]

*Do I have to blacklist or remove nouveau ? Or how do I get the 346 driver to work?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was going on. The nouveau driver uses the 346 proprietary driver binary. So essentially everytime the newer driver is released the Nouveau "driver" uses whatever the most recent one and repackages itself.

Comment: Indeed!  Confirmed (and upvoted!)  **;-)**  (And a small edit so that the next user asking the same question will find it easier and can upvote it too!)

Comment: Thanks. I have a question. I changed back to my primary laptop. Which has an optimus chipset but has the same specs (GT 750M gfx card). When I install nvidia-346 on this machine, the Nouveau driver isn't used. The driver used is nvidia-346

Comment: That would be a new machine, different settings, different install and [a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).  ;-)